# Drupal Apache Solr How to process all the results and not only 10?

Tags: 7, search

I have a Drupal 7 website with apache solr search engine, and i want to access to all the results via my custom module before it is displayed, so i used this hook [hook_apachesolr_process_results](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!apachesolr!apachesolr.api.php/function/hook_apachesolr_process_results/7) and as it says in it description

> This is invoked by apachesolr_search.module for the whole resultset returned in a search.

and that works good as long as your results are less then 10, but if your results are more then 10 results, then this hook will only process 10 by 10 (and 10 is the number of results that are returned in search page by default) so it only process the results that are currently displayed in the current page.

my question is there is a way to access all the results and not only the 10 results that are displayed in the current page?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, Solr returns 10 results by default but you can tell him to return more with the `rows` parameter :

> The `rows` parameter specify the maximum number of documents from the complete result
>   set to return to the client for every request.

You can overwrite the default by implementing [`hook_apachesolr_query_alter()`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!apachesolr!apachesolr.api.php/function/hook_apachesolr_query_alter/7) in your custom module. e.g :

```
function hook_apachesolr_query_alter($query) {
  $query->replaceParam('rows', '1000'); // Note that high value increases response time
}
```

Maybe you can do the same from the apachesolr configuration page but I'm not sure (can't check right now). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can both preprocess, https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_search_results/7 and https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_search_result/7, and theme search results (even with solr), with search-results.tpl.php and search-result.tpl.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i already tested prepocess_search_results and the returned resultset don't pass 10, i want a way to retrieve all the results so i can do some statistics.